# Sending commands to the active program in a screen session?

Tags: linux, gnu, gnu-screen

I've got a server running inside a screen session, and I want to send this program a command. I thought screen -X was my answer, but all that gives me access to is screen commands (title, exec, etc).

I need to be able to send the command as if I was typing it into the program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `screen`'s `-p` and `-X` options in conjunction with the `exec` command.

Try `screen -X exec ".\!\!" echo foo`, for example, to send "foo" to the currently-running program in the screen.

You might also want to try `screen -X exec ".!" echo foo` if the first command is not working.

Comment: I've been all over that damn manual, it hasn't helped me at all.

Comment: I get "Cannot exec '.\!\!': No such file or directory"
The entire exec section made no sense to me

Comment: And removing the quotes around .\!\! makes it do nothing at all

Comment: `screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -X exec .\!\! echo foo` . The only problem is that you have to attach to a screen session atleast once before sending anything will work, so you cannot echo to a freshly created detached screen session (you have to attach and detach first)